# Get gradle property from settings

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

So i am trying to transition my app to Kotlin DSL the issue i am facing is with accessing gradle.properties the way i was doing with groovy was like that, i am trying to access `gradle.properties` props from my `settings.gradle.kts` file

```
def propName = 'prop.name.something'
def propDisabled = Boolean.valueOf(properties[propName])
```

I tried several ways of accessing it with settings.extra[propName].toBoolean. It just seems there should be more straight way to access those properties?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The proper way to access a property declared in `gradle.properties` in `settings.gradle.kts` is by delegating it to the `settings` object:

```kotlin
val myProperty: String by settings
```

<sup>Note that it is mandatory to specify the property type `String` explicitly here.</sup>

This will get the property `myProperty` from the `gradle.properties` file. Note that if you use it in the `pluginManagement { ... }` block, then the property declaration needs to be placed inside `pluginManagement { ... }`, too, as this block is evaluated before everything else in the script.

However, if a property name contains symbols that are illegal in Kotlin identifiers, such as `.`, which is not allowed even in [backticked identifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/declaring-variables.html#scopes-and-naming), then you can't access it as a delegated property. There's no way to access such a property from the Gradle model as of Gradle 6.7, but, given that `gradle.properties` is just a `.properties` file, you can read it into a Java `Properties` instance:

```kotlin
val properties = File(rootDir, "gradle.properties").inputStream().use { 
    java.util.Properties().apply { load(it) } 
}
val propNameSomething = properties.getValue("prop.name.something") as String
```

Comment: I also noted that `settings` object does not have a `findProperty` method, and that as such `val myProperty: String by settings` will fail if the property is absent. In that case only reading the property file helped.

Comment: Actually I stumbled on another option using the `extra` object : `val myProperty = extra.has("myProperty").let { if (it) extra.get("myProperty") as String else null}`

Comment: How to do it without `kts`? Groovy is still the default supported standard.